# double vs Double as Floating Point Numbers in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, double

My question is two-part.

1. Why does the following work fine in Eclipse? Isn't "Double" a class?

```
    Double h = 2.5;
    double j = 2;
```

2. Why does "Double" above give me an error when I don't assign a decimal value to it, but "double" is fine whether or not I assign a decimal value to it?

Comment: [Autoboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As was already mentioned, the term is autoboxing. The object wrappers for the primitive types will automatically convert.

As to your second part,

```
Double a = 2;
```

Doesn't work since 2 is not a double and the auto boxing only works between the same types.  In this case `2` is an int.

But if you cast it.

```
Double a = (double)2;
```

works just fine.

```
double a = 2;
```

works because an int can be automatically converted to a double.  But going the
other way doesn't work.

```
int a = 2.2; // not permitted.
```

Check out the [Section on conversions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-5.html). In the Java Language Specification.  Warning that it can sometimes be difficult to read.

**Amended Answer.**

In java you can cast up or down or have narrowing or widening casts (going from a 32 bit to 16 bit) value is narrowing.  But I tend to think about it is `losing vs not losing` something.  In most cases if you have the potential to lose part of value in assignment, you need to cast, otherwise you don't (See exceptions at end).  Here are some examples.

```
long a = 2; // 2 is an integer but going to a long doesn't `lose` precision.
int b = 2L; // here, 2 is a long and the assignment is not permitted.  Even 
            // though a long 2 will fit inside an int, the cast is still 
            // required.
int b = (int)2L;  // Fine, but clearly a contrived case
```

Same for floating point.

```
float a = 2.2f; // fine
double b = a;   // no problem, not precision lost
float c = b;    // can't do it, as it requires a cast.

double c = 2.2f; // a float to a double, again a not problem.
float d = 2.2;  // 2.2 is a double by default so requires a cast or the float designator.
float d = (float)2.2;
```

**Exceptions**

No cast is required when converting from `int to float` or `long to double`.  However, precision can still be lost since the floats only have `24` bits of precision and doubles only have `53` bits of precision.

To see this for `ints` you can run the following:

```
        for (int i = Integer.MAX_VALUE; i > Integer.MAX_VALUE-100; i--) {
            float s = i;
            int t = (int)s; // normal cast required
            if (i != t) {
                System.out.println (i + " " + t);
            }
        }
```

Comment: That was a very swift and effective response. I'm fairly new here, so it seems I can neither upvote nor mark your answer as the correct one to my question. So, I'll just say thank you.

Comment: You can accept it after 10 minutes (i think).  You need 15 rep to upvote.  But don't worry about.  And you're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Double is a wrapper class, creating a new Double casts a primitive variable of the SAME type into a Object. For `Double h = 2`, you are wrapping a `int` into a Double. Since wrapping only works between same types, if you want your `Double` variable be 2, then you should use

`Double h = 2.0;`